# Use CSS to replace the content of elements based on the content of another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write some CSS that might take the page title (defined by a h1 element's content) and stick that content into every element with the class "DocTitle". I'm limited to using CSS and HTML.

Suggestions?

```
<head>
<style>
.DocTitle {
    content: element(runningheader);

.pagetitle h1 {
    position: running(runningheader);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="DocTitle"></div>

<h1 class="pagetitle">This is the page title</h1>

<span class="DocTitle">This should be replaced</span>

</body>
```

Based on research, I would have thought this might have worked, but I think it only works if you use page at-rules, and I don't think I can apply content to a class in an at-rule. I'm not 100% on that though, because I'm not really sure what I can and cannot do in an at-rule. For reference, this is for use in generating print media.

Comment: I thought you could only use content in pseudo :before and :after elements. Am I wrong?

Comment: [The CSS content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) only works on the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

Comment: I wasn't really sure. I tried it with those, and it didn't work either.